# MVC3 db.SaveChanges() INSERT statement error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am following MVC music store similarly. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-9

When I doing create orderDetails, I have got error with inner exception.

Could you help me what does it mean?

"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_OrderDetails_Product\". The conflict occurred in database \"rentalDB\", table \"dbo.Product\", column 'productId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

Do I need to check in SQL Server? I don't know why it errors happen..

Can you give me some advice? I am giving you some my code.

Please help me. Thanks.

```
public int CreateOrder(Order order)
    {
        decimal orderTotal = 0;

        var cartItems = GetCartItems();

        // Iterate over the items in the cart, adding the order details for each
        foreach (var item in cartItems)
        {
            var orderDetail = new OrderDetails
            {
                productId = item.Product.productId,
                orderId = order.orderId,
                unitPrice = item.priceValue,
                rentalPeriod = item.rentalPeriod,
                startDate = item.dateCreated.AddDays(2),
                endDate = item.dateCreated.AddDays(2 + item.rentalPeriod),
                quantity = item.count
            };

            // Set the order total of the shopping cart
            orderTotal += (item.count * item.priceValue);

            db.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);

        }

        // Set the order's total to the orderTotal count
        order.total = orderTotal;

        // Save the order
        db.SaveChanges(); //I have error in here!!!

        // Empty the shopping cart
        EmptyCart();

        // Return the OrderId as the confirmation number
        return order.orderId;
    }
```

Here is viewModel

```
public class ShoppingCartViewModel
{
    public List<Cart> CartItems { get; set; }
    public decimal CartTotal { get; set; }
}
```

Here is Cart

```
public class Cart
{
    [Key]
    public int recordId { get; set; }
    public string cartId { get; set; }
    public int productId { get; set; }
    public decimal priceValue { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int rentalPeriod { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Here is Product

```
 public class Product
{
    [Key] public int productId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select category")]
    public int categoryId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill in model name")]
    [DisplayName("Model name")]
    public String model { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Description")]
    public String description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Original price")]
    public decimal price { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill in stock of product")]
    [DisplayName("Stock")]
    public int stock { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not set FK in OrderDetails..

That's what I have got error before.

When I create FK between OrderDetails and Order, it will work.